# uname: command not found

Tags: makefile, fortran, export, intel-fortran

I try to run a makefile and I need to set the path in which the ifort compiler is located. I try the following line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/081/bin/intel:/usr/bin`

in a past makefile something like that worked well. But now, and I almost sure I miss the correct spelling of the export line, doesn't want to work properly.

In fact it gave to me the following error message:

`/opt/.../intel64/ifort: uname: command not found`

It seams that it do not recover this address.

Should I probability change `/opt/../bin/...` whit `/include/` or others path in the Compiler directory?

Is maybe the last `:/usr/bin` part of the address incorrect?

**EDIT 1**

I try to follow the suggestions in the comments using, at the second line of the Makefile, the follow line:

`export PATH:=$(PATH):/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/081/bin/intel64:/usr/bin`

but I receive the following error message:

`MyGa.f90:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to "__intel_new_feature_proc_init"`

Is it possible I have to change the line of the `export` command from the second to the first one or the `:/usr/bin` directory path?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That `export` line is in a makefile or a shell script?

Comment: For the intel compiler you should source the environment script to make sure all the variables ifort expects are set.  e.g. `source /opt/intel/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64`

Comment: @EtanReisner and francescalus:  is the second line of a makefile

Comment: In a makefile that line needs to be `export PATH=$(PATH):/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/081/bin/intel:/usr/bin`.

Comment: @EtanReisner is right, except you have to use `:=` here not `=`, else you'll get a recursive variable definition error.

Comment: Type `which uname`.  It will either tell you where it is or tell you it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

is uname present in the bin?
try this:

```
ls -l /bin/uname
```

to check if it's present
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35032 Jan 18  2018 /bin/uname` (if present)

if it is present then check your PATH variable

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: What if it is not present? I get this output -> ls: /bin/uname: No such file or directory

Comment: Type `which uname` to find out where uname lives and if it is on your path.